# Word "Array" appearing on my Bootstrap View Modal

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been trying to get my bootstrap modal to display the needed content without error. As I found a way to connect the modal to the phpmyadmin database, I cannot get the word "Array" to go away. Here is my code:

```
<?php echo $announcement = getRowById('announcement',$_GET['id']); ?>

<div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo $announcement['name']; ?> <small><?php echo $announcement['date']; ?></small></h4>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
               <tr> <?php echo $announcement['name']; ?></tr>
                <tr><?php echo $announcement['description']; ?></tr>


<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> <?php _e('Close'); ?></button>
</div>
  <script>
```

It is coming from the first row (php echo $announcement) - if I remove this, my content gets removed as well - does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I am fairly new to all this, any guidance would be incredibly appreciated.

See image of the modal example:
[image]

Comment: It means `$announcement['name']` contains an array and not just a value. You have to get the value(s) out of it and display those. Like `$announcement['name'][0]` for example.

Comment: Probably because `$announcement['name'];` returns an array. How does your `$announcement` data structure look like? Also, a `<tr>` is not a valid child node of `<div>`. It should be nested inside `<table><tbody>`

Comment: Remove the word `echo` in the first line.

Comment: @AbraCadaver this worked! Wow- more simple than I made it out to be. Thank you much!

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: Feel free to delete the question